# Android MediaPlayer or SoundPool?

Tags: android

When I use mediaplayer on click button, after several clicks the sound disappears. When I use soundpool, the time is too short to play the effect sound. Can anybody please help me with this?

Comment: MediaPlayer is for long audios like music, songs, when SoundPool is for short ones (like sound effects when clicking a button), what is your exact need?

Comment: What if my sound effect has 20 sec? SoundPoll doesn't work this around. Sorry. I'm new at it.

Comment: You can test my code in the answer.

Comment: @matthiasbe I was gonna put my code here. However I thought was too complicated and so unnecessary to post so as to avoid you guys to waste time understanding it. But thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood your audio is 20 s. So you can use this code on your button click:

```
if (mediaPlayer != null){
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer.release();
    mediaPlayer = null;
}
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio_file);
mediaPlayer.start();
```

The first if statement is to take care that it will keep playing how much ever you clicked the button.